# Neo4j Cypher Query include start node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to list all movies that I act in and the sum of actors in each movie, but the query below only returns the sum of actors apart from me and will not return movie which without other actors.

```
start me=node({0}) 
match me-[:ACTS_IN]->movie<-[:ACTS_IN]-otherActors 
return movie, count(*) as actorSum
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to break it up with `WITH`. The problem with your query is that you're claiming the `me` node in the first part of the `match`, so `me` can't ever be in `otherActors`.

```
start me=node({0}) 
match me-[:ACTS_IN]->movie
with movie   
match movie<-[:ACTS_IN]-actors 
return movie, count(*) as actorSum
```

Comment: That's was what I was looking for. Follow up question though, will that have a performance impact?